# Multiple usage of if(array_key_exists.. in my Model constructor, how to make it cleaner?

Tags: php, laravel, refactoring

I am currently working on a big model of mine, which has to instantiate and attach a lot of other related models IF the parameters are supplied in the attributes provided.

Here is a snippet of what it looks like now.

```
public function __construct($input)
{
  parent::__construct($input);
  $this->fill($input);
  $this->save();
  $this->initializeSomeValues($input);
  $this->thingie()->save(new SuperThingie());
  if(array_key_exists ('client_image', $input)) $this->clientImage()->save(new ClientImage($input['client_image']));
  if(array_key_exists ('client_names', $input)) $this->initializeClientNames($input);
  if(array_key_exists ('client_saiyan_level', $input)) $this->clientSaiyanLevel()->save(new ClientSaiyanLevel($input['client_saiyan_level']));
//...
}
```

You get the idea, i've got a bit more of those and its not that beautiful, maybe someone has an idea to make it cleaner?

Thanks in advance for your time guys,

Martin

Comment: You can use the composite pattern if you want to have a very clean code.

Comment: You are doing different things in each case after the if, so it may not be so easy to clean this up so much. But, maybe if you take a bigger step back and figure out why it is that you have to keep checking if an array key exists, maybe you will be able to come up with a cleaner solution. For example, starting with how the $input array is generated, maybe there is a way to not just throw everything in there? Just throwing out suggestions

Comment: Thanks for your insight guys, i made it cleaner by extracting everything i could in various other functions atm. I'm sure there is a better way but the code is pretty clean as it is, so it will suffice!